# Sorting rule: display highest discount

Tags: commerce-cloud

is there a way to display highest discount value using sorting rule? For example, I want to show items that have the highest discount only - item A used to be $100 now $20, item B used to be $100 now $50. So item A should show first then item B will be shown next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to have a custom attribute on the products to sort them based on the discount.

You can, however, enable a "Promotion Refinement" via a feature switch and some code changes:

https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/search_and_navigation/b2c_configuring_catalog_level_search_refinement_definitions.html

https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/search_and_navigation/b2c_promotion_refinement_code_changes.html?resultof=%22%70%72%6f%6d%6f%74%69%6f%6e%22%20%22%70%72%6f%6d%6f%74%22%20%22%72%65%66%69%6e%65%6d%65%6e%74%22%20%22%72%65%66%69%6e%22%20